# getting an error page, uploading a file worked last week and I have made no changes

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, forms

here is my JSF/HTML page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


<body>


        <ui:composition template="./templates/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="#{controls.designAuth}">
                Welcome Report Designer!<br /><br />

                <div id="fileUpload">



                    <form name="myForm" action="../UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">

                        <b>Make sure your filename is meaningful (eg. WasteByMachineReport.jrxml)</b><br /><br />

                        Please specify a file:<input type="file" name="file" size="40"/><br /><br />
                        Number of parameters: <select name="numSelect" id='numSelect' onchange="draw_param_dropdowns();">
                            <option selected="selected" >0</option>
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                    <option>6</option>
                                                    <option>7</option>
                                                    <option>8</option>
                                                    <option>9</option>
                                                    <option>10</option>
                                                    <option>11</option>
                                                    <option>12</option>
                                                    <option>13</option>
                                                    <option>14</option>
                                                    <option>15</option>
                                              </select><br />
                                              <br /><br />
                                              <table border="0">
                                                  <tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><span id ="tabletitles" style ="display: none;">Parameter Name</span></td><td><span width="200" id ="tabletitles2" style ="display: none;">Data Type</span></td></tr>

                                                  <tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td>
                                                          <input type="text" name="P1" id="P1" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype1" name="Ptype1" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                                          </td></tr>
                                             <tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P2" id="P2" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype2" name="Ptype2" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr> <tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P3" id="P3" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype3" name="Ptype3" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P4" id="P4" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype4" name="Ptype4" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P5" id="P5" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype5" name="Ptype5" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P6" id="P6" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype6" name="Ptype6" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr> <tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P7" id="P7" style="display:none;"></input> </td><td><select id="Ptype7" name="Ptype7" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P8" id="P8" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype8" name="Ptype8" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P9" id="P9" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype9" name="Ptype9" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P10" id="P10" style="display:none;"></input></td><td> <select id="Ptype10" name="Ptype10" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P11" id="P11" style="display:none;"></input></td><td> <select id="Ptype11" name="Ptype11" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P12" id="P12" style="display:none;"></input> </td><td><select id="Ptype12" name="Ptype12" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td><input type="text" name="P13" id="P13" style="display:none;"></input> </td><td><select id="Ptype13" name="Ptype13" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P14" id="P14" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype14" name="Ptype14" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                             </td></tr><tr style="background-color:#dddddd;color:black;"><td> <input type="text" name="P15" id="P15" style="display:none;"></input></td><td><select id="Ptype15" name="Ptype15" style="display:none;">
                                                                                                   <option>Date</option>
                                                                                                   <option>String</option>
                                                                                                   <option>Number</option></select>
                                              </td></tr></table>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">


                                                    function draw_param_dropdowns(){

                                                     for (var x = 1; x <= 15; x++) {
                                                            document.getElementById('Ptype' + x).style.display='none';
                                                            document.getElementById('P' + x).style.display='none';

                                                            document.getElementById("tabletitles").style.display = 'none';
                                                            document.getElementById("tabletitles2").style.display = 'none';

                                                        }
                                                                if (document.getElementById("numSelect").selectedIndex >=1)
                                                                    {document.getElementById("tabletitles").style.display = 'block';
                                                                     document.getElementById("tabletitles2").style.display = 'block';}


                                                        for (var y = 1; y <= document.getElementById("numSelect").selectedIndex; y++) {
                                                            document.getElementById('Ptype' + y).style.display = 'block';
                                                            document.getElementById('P' + y).style.display = 'block';
                                                        }
                                                    }


    </script>

                        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>

                    </form>

                </div>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    Not Authorized 
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

and here is the java servlet that was like I said working to upload files a week ago or so

```
/*\_________________________________________________
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
\*///-----------------------------------------------

package DBFunctions;

// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.*;

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
   private int maxFileSize = 200 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
   private File file ;
   private String name;
   private String reportTitle;


    @Override
   public void init(){
      // Get the file location where it would be stored.
      filePath = "c:\\Projects\\WebApplication8\\web\\uploads\\";

   }
    @Override
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request



      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      request.getParameter(null);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>");
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");

         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet Upload</title>");
      out.println("</head>");

      out.println("<body><div style='position:absolute;width:500px;height:700px;left:35%;background-color:#d2d2d2;'><center><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />");
      //out.println(filePath);
      while ( i.hasNext () )
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            name = fileName;
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath +
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath +
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
            }
            fi.write( file );


            out.println("<br /><br />Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
         }
      }
      out.println("<br /><br /><a href='/WebApplication8/faces/it.xhtml'>Add New File to / Edit Menu Tree</a><br /><br /><br />");
      out.println("<a href='/WebApplication8/faces/designer.xhtml'>Back</a></center></div>");

      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//            String params  =request.getParameter("numParams");
//
//
//             int numParams = Integer.parseInt(params);
//
//            out.println(numParams);

            DBConnect db = new DBConnect();

            boolean result = db.DBConnectAndUpdate("INSERT INTO PLANT.APPLIC VALUES (9999, '" + name + "','R','" + "',0,'eng')");


      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------



      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");


   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }

   }
    @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
                getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
   }
}
```

and here is the error

I have looked at the error and looked through the entire servlet for missing semi colons or something silly, but I haven't made any changes literally since the last time it worked

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:334)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameterValues(Parameters.java:195)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:240)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1066)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:355)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorRequestWrapper.getParameter(MonitorRequestWrapper.java:199)
    DBFunctions.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:54)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.26 logs.
```

Comment: *note I did not write the upload servlet, but I did add the code to write to the database, but that was months ago and it all worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your servlet code:

```
request.getParameter(null);
```

A few steps into this method call java.util.Hashtable.get(null) gets called, which throws the NPE. This is the expected behavior, see [java.util.Hashtable.get(Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29), because null as a key is not allowed for a Hashtable. This is exactly what the Stacktrace tells you. If it worked before, the code must have changed somehow because this line will always fail, and it would have failed a few weeks or months ago, too. (And it doesn't make too much sense in the first place).

Comment: ya let me try and take it out? or should it be changed, its part of the original servlet that I downloaded from the web...

Comment: I removed it, in case someone else reads this and wants to know what solved it

Comment: well thanks for the help @xor_eq worked great
and @BalusC thanks for your useful input